# Tricky question about... a infinite reduced row echelon matrix

Tags: matrices, limits, polynomials, factorial, gaussian-elimination

Let's say I want to write the polynomial function $p(x)$ that passes the points $(1,1!)$, $(2,2!)$, $\ldots$, $(n,n!)$, that will be of the form $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_nx^n$. What I need to do is to set is the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n = 1! \\
a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 + \ldots + 2^na_n = 2! \\
\vdots \\
a_0 + na_1 + n^2a_2 + \ldots + n^na_n = n!
\end{cases}
$$
I can just consider the augmented matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 & 1 \\
            1 & 2 & 4 & \ldots & 2^n & 2 \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
            1 & n-1 & (n-1)^2 & \ldots & (n-1)^n & (n-1)! \\
            1 & n & n^2 & \ldots & n^n & n!
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and apply the Gaussian elimination. What I would want to know is if $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}{a_n}$ exists, so if the $n$-th coefficient of the polynomial $p(x)$ converges to something, if is ever possible to know that.

Comment: None of these coefficients have a limit.  All alternate in sign and increase (fairly rapidly) in magnitude.  For $n=10$, this polynomial is $$4.04667 x^9-178.422 x^8+3391.48 x^7-36322.2 x^6+240365. x^5-1.0133\times 10^6 x^4+2.70142\times 10^6 x^3-4.35019\times 10^6 x^2+3.78977\times 10^6 x-1.33496\times 10^6  \text{.}$$  For $n=11$ it is $$4.41455 x^{10}-238.754 x^9+5648.79 x^8-76732.7 x^7+660175. x^6-3.7418\times 10^6 x^5+1.40709\times 10^7 x^4-3.44228\times 10^7 x^3+5.19511\times 10^7 x^2-4.31309\times 10^7 x+1.46846\times 10^7  \text{.}$$

Comment: @EricTowers so, probably, $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty}{a_n} = +\infty$?

Comment: No.  Alternating signs means that the limits don't go to either infinity.

Comment: @EricTowers the sign for $a_n$ is always positive.

Comment: Mis-recalled that you wanted limits of coefficients for fixed degrees.  The leading coefficient does go to $+\infty$ almost linearly.  It's approximately $\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}n+\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}}$.

Comment: @EricTowers that’s an interesting result as well! How did you get it? Interpolation?

Comment: Yes.  Generated the first 1000 leading coefficients and noticed the successive differences were very consistently around $0.4$.  Plotted them, saw an approximate line (with a couple of displaced points near $n = 1$.  Linear fit the last $900$ of them.  Recognized the constant and linear coefficients as $1/\mathrm{e}$.  (cont...)

Comment: I then looked at the induction for row reduction of the matrix.  The first thing I noticed is you have too many columns.  You have $n$ rows and should have $n+1$ columns, but you have $n+2$.  So the bottom row should be $1, n, n^2, \dots, n^{n-1}, n!$.  Then the coefficients submatrix is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  I used one of the referenced inverses, pushed the algebra around for a bit until it seemed plausible that the linear fit matched the "inverse times vector of factorials" in the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.